# Creating a postcard with LaTeX

Tags: cards

I want to create a postcard with LaTeX, say 3x5 or 4x6 in.  I use LaTeX for many things, but up to now I've used MS Word for postcards.  Now I'd like to do more interesting things with postcards that would leverage LaTeX's capabilities.  Where should I start?  Is there already a package, or a simple setting, that will do the trick?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Simply use the [geometry package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/geometry) to change the page size of your document.

I used LaTeX to create my own wedding reception invitations and RSVP cards using the article class, the geometry package, some parboxes, and a flowerly-looking font. The result was very good. (I'd post examples, but it hasn't happened yet and I don't want to inadvertantly invite everyone on TeX.SX).

EDIT

For fun, here's a simple postcard:

```
\documentclass{article}

\pagestyle{empty}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\usepackage[paperwidth=5in, 
    paperheight=3.5in,
    left=0.50in,
    right=0.50in,
    top=0.50in,
    bottom=0.50in]{geometry}

\begin{document}
Hello, World!

This is just a little note to see how you're doing. I haven't see out since that big party in stdlib's house. I hope you've gotten out of that infinite loop I wrote after my 5th beer.

\vfill
\raggedleft
Your friend, \\
Printf

\newpage

\raggedright
return 0; \\
123 Main St \\
Big City, ES 12345
\vfill
\centering
\parbox{2in}{Mr World \\
123 Knuth Dr \\
Central Processor, UT 0x000}
\vfill
\end{document}
```

result:

[image]

Comment: Just change the date and the place; then go at the indicated date and place to see how many TeX.SX users got trapped. :-) Best wishes for your wedding!

Comment: good description, but I'd have to see a MWE to vote :) could you add one?

Comment: Added a simple postcard example.

Comment: For this you might want to use the `textpos` package. It lets you position text freely on the page, so you don't have to mess with fills to get the positioning right.