# How to make a postcard in LaTeX?

Tags: tikz-pgf

It should look like this:

[image: Postcard]

It should be a a4paper where the left half is a picture. On that picture should be a title in the font calligra. At the right side, there should be a text in the font initfamily.

Here is what I tried:

```
\documentclass[11pt, landscape, twocolumns]{memoir}

%graphic packages
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm,includeheadfoot]{geometry}
\pagestyle{empty}
\parindent0pt

%fonts
\input Elzevier.fd
\newcommand*\initfamily{\usefont{U}{Elzevier}{xl}{n}}
\usepackage{calligra}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
\iffalse
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{some_image.jpg}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\fi
\initfamily{Hochzeit}

\calligra{text}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You might find http://ctan.org/pkg/cfr-initials useful. Disclaimer: I wrote it. However, the packages themselves are so simple that even I probably managed to do them reasonably correctly. It means you don't have to input the font definition files etc. any more: you can just load the package(s) you want and use the commands provided.

Comment: Completely unrelated: [Creating a postcard with LaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/56235/5764)

Comment: Now, if you want the back side of the postcard, try this: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/200349/how-can-i-make-a-postcard-template

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One option:

[image]

The idea is to use a `tikzpicture` and `\node`s with the proper settings to place the elements at the desired locations; since internal calculations are involved, two runs are needed for the elements to appear at their final locations. Feel free to adjust the settings according to your needs.

The code:

```
\documentclass[11pt, landscape]{memoir}

%graphic packages
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}

\pagestyle{empty}
\parindent0pt

%fonts
\input Elzevier.fd
\newcommand*\initfamily{\usefont{U}{Elzevier}{xl}{n}}
\usepackage{calligra}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  remember picture,
  overlay,
  mytext/.style={text width=\dimexpr0.5\paperwidth-20pt\relax,inner xsep=10pt}
]
  \node[anchor=north west,inner sep=0] 
    at (current page.north west)
    (image) 
    {\includegraphics[width=0.5\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{mushrooms}};
  \node[anchor=north,text=white,scale=2] 
    at ([yshift=-1cm]image.north)
    {\initfamily{Hochzeit}};
  \node[anchor=north west,text width=0.5\paperwidth,inner sep=0pt,minimum height=\paperheight] 
    at (current page.north)
    (textbox)
    {};
  \node[anchor=north west,mytext] 
    at ([yshift=-2cm]textbox.north west)
    (text1)
    {\calligra{text and some other text}};
  \node[anchor=north west,mytext] 
    at ([yshift=-5cm]textbox.north west)
    (text2)
    {\calligra{text and some other text}};
  \node[anchor=south,mytext] 
    at ([yshift=3cm]textbox.south)
    (text3)
    {\calligra{text and some other text}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

### Update

Using the `Elzevier` package from the [`cfr-initials`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/cfr-initials) bundle, there's no need to input the font definition files:

```
\documentclass[11pt, landscape]{memoir}

%graphic packages
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}

\pagestyle{empty}
\parindent0pt

%fonts
\usepackage{calligra}
\usepackage{Elzevier}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  remember picture,
  overlay,
  mytext/.style={text width=\dimexpr0.5\paperwidth-20pt\relax,inner xsep=10pt}
]
  \node[anchor=north west,inner sep=0] 
    at (current page.north west)
    (image) 
    {\includegraphics[width=0.5\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{mushrooms}};
  \node[anchor=north,text=white,scale=2] 
    at ([yshift=-1cm]image.north)
    {\elz{Hochzeit}};
  \node[anchor=north west,text width=0.5\paperwidth,inner sep=0pt,minimum height=\paperheight] 
    at (current page.north)
    (textbox)
    {};
  \node[anchor=north west,mytext] 
    at ([yshift=-2cm]textbox.north west)
    (text1)
    {\calligra{text and some other text}};
  \node[anchor=north west,mytext] 
    at ([yshift=-5cm]textbox.north west)
    (text2)
    {\calligra{text and some other text}};
  \node[anchor=south,mytext] 
    at ([yshift=3cm]textbox.south)
    (text3)
    {\calligra{text and some other text}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. And could it be that you are the Tikz-guru here? :-) ... everytime I have trouble with Tikz and need some code to look at I find your posts here :D ... thank you for that, that is really helpful!

Comment: @Dr.HenrietteB.Fröhlich You're welcome and thanks for your kind words. I am glad I could help. I updated my answer with some improvements. I wish I were a TikZ-guru; I'm just a TikZ-enthusiast :-)

Comment: There is now a package for each of the initials fonts, by the way. So you don't have to input the font definition file etc. in your document. I may, however, have a slight bias in its favour.

Comment: @cfr Which package are you referring to? Why would you have a bias? Did you write it?

Comment: http://ctan.org/pkg/cfr-initials. They are pretty much the simplest packages can get without doing literally nothing whatsoever.

Comment: @cfr Great! I hace to leave now, but when I get back home I'll update my answer using your package.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina That would be an honour. (But I won't be able to vote your answer up again!)

Comment: @cfr Answer updated. Nice packages!

Comment: Thank you. Thank Harish Kumar, though. He wanted me to post sample of the packages and also debugged the documentation. (The packages I made several years ago but I don't write documentation for myself. Though sometimes I think I should.)